# WISH + would stop popping up/stopped popping up

Tags: wish

> 1 I wish ads *would stop popping up* when I read articles on the
> Internet.
>
> 2 I wish ads *stopped popping up* when I read articles on the Internet.

I think that both are correct. What do you think?

Comment: It would be more natural to say _I wish they didn't [keep] popping up_ rather than _I wish they stopped popping up_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're both correct, and in most circumstances would mean precisely the same thing. The two sentences' grammatical structure is different, however, and there are circumstances in which they'll have different meanings.

They both express a hypothetical, subjunctive mood; "I wish ads stopped popping up" being a subjunctive about the habitual present (with the present tense taking a step into the past), whereas "I wish ads would stop popping up" is structurally a subjunctive about the [immediate] future (in which case "will" takes one step backwards, turning itself into "would").

Consider another example: "I wish you didn't go away so soon" as compared to "I wish you wouldn't go away so soon". In the first case, the speaker would usually be implying that the listener has a regular habit of going away sooner than the speaker would like. The speaker is most likely wishing the impossible: that something that habitually happens in reality didn't happen. In the second case, there is no such implication: while the speaker could be saying the very same thing as the above (possibly implying a criticism of the listener), they may simply be anticipating that the listener is about to leave (perhaps they have to for some reason) and expressing regret that it must happen.

Anyway, taken literally, "I wish it didn't happen" is a wish for a counterfactual hypothesis: a wish that something that does indeed happen didn't, whereas "I wish it wouldn't happen" can be interpreted as a (still hypothetical) wish something that either habitually happens or that one fully expects to happen in the near future, wouldn't happen *from now on*.

Mostly there's no effective difference between the two wishes, but just occasionally there is.

To illustrate the point, think of the future sentence "I'll do the shopping tomorrow." You could answer it with "I wish you wouldn't, because you always forget something"; but you're unlikely to answer with "I wish you didn't ...".

Personally, I tend to prefer the "wouldn't" form in most circumstances, as there's rarely much point in wishing a counterfactual about the habitual present.

Comment: A person is going to smoke, unwrapping a pack of cigarettes. Which one is better? 1 I wish you wouldn't smoke now! 2 I wish you didn't smoke now. Having read your profile, I am none the wiser as to whether your first language is English.

Comment: Definitely "wouldn't"! It's unambiguously a wish about the immediate future. Great example, by the way. "I wish you didn't smoke" means something very different!

I'm Irish. Yep, my first language is English.  I was an English teacher for *ages*.

Comment: The rub is that I was told by an English native speaker that they preferred to say "I wish you didn't smoke NOW!" to mean what you would say by saying "I wish you wouldn't smoke now!". I am not saying that you are wrong I am just stating the fact that there must be a lack of unanimousness among natives on the matter.

Comment: If I were a little more old-fashioned, I'd go so far as to say that your native speaker was wrong! The now doesn't literally mean right now at this moment, and even if it did, in standard English, it'd probably be more natural to say "I wish you weren't smoking now"! ;-)

Comment: I think you mean " I wish you were not going to smoke now!"

Comment: That's not what I mean, because that's about the immediate future too (or about someone's immediate intentions), not about this very moment. But your sentence is certainly grammatically correct, and logically consistent with the situation. It's just a little unusual, possibly because directly wishing something about someone's immediate intentions is rare. It's usually about the unwelcome immediate prospect of getting smoke in your face.

Comment: I disagree with initial "they are both valid". *I wish you stopped smoking* is syntactically invalid.

Comment: @Jaime: I'm not sure I can articulate exactly *why*, but I'm pretty sure the only valid parsing of "I wish you didn't smoke NOW!" requires adverbial ***now*** to be modifying ***wish***, not ***smoke*** (i.e. - maybe in the past I didn't care whether you smoked or not, but ***now*** I definitely wish you didn't smoke).